# How to encrypt data in android

Tags: java, android, web-services

I am using PHP WebService to send my data to server. Somehow my data is too much important and for the same I have to use some encryption algorithm to send my data to webservice. And then webservice has to decrypt that data and further proceed. Same way, when WebService sends a response, response should be encrypted and from client side it would be decypted.

Can anyone suggest me what algorithm or what method I should implement for the above issue?

Comment: Searching this site returned lots of results: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816771/android-encryption -- the first one with an accepted answer has code

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/encrypt-decrypt-between-android-and-php) is an snippet to comunicate with PHP servers.. it should be much difference with any other language.

Also, you must also find the way to obfuscate the key as much as you can on your android apk can be "extracted" by someone with malicious intentions and look up for the encryption key.

Comment: Following that model will lead to every instance of the application using the same key. That's only suitable if you don't plan to distribute the application.

Comment: As I say, it's not the most secure way, but I does encrypt the data between the application and the webserver..

Answer (score 1):

You should use [TLS (also known as SSL)](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/package-summary.html).