# Encrypt data in Android

Tags: java, php, android, web-services, cryptography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to encrypt data in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120146/how-to-encrypt-data-in-android)

i want  to encrypt data and then send that data to php web service.Now Php webservice will decrypt the same data.is there any way to handle this situation that works for both?

Comment: If you manage to find a standard encryption algorithm and there are libraries in both php and java that supports it, then yes.

Comment: Reported for question spam. You just posted that question for the 2nd time a few minutes ago and now you deleted it to repost for the 3rd time without the duplicate warnings/negative votes.

Comment: Nice tone you got there. I really hope that you deleted that comment on your own. Everything else would be sad.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, use a secure http conneciton. The [HttpsURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html) class should help you do this.